# What operations can you perform with bool and int operators in C++?

Tags: c++, types, operation, boolean-operations

I have a variable, which *value* can **differ from 0 to 1**, so I would like to use a **bool type** for holding this value.

In *C++* based on this idea what operations can I do, the type of the *first operand*  being **bool** and the *second's* being **int or float**?

For example, is this valid?

```
bool exists;
int value;
(...)
value += exists;
value *= exists;
```

If yes, until *c++* converts these values into their **binary appropriates** and finds no problems doing the *operations* on those *binary numbers*, it is **valid** to do the operations with **operands that differ**?

Comment: interesting, `bool b = false; b += 10;` compiles on gcc, I wonder what that mean though

Comment: @Slava, it means `bool` is promoted to `int` with a result of 0, than arithmetic operation results in 10, which is than converted to `bool` with a result of 1.

Comment: @SergeyA funny, how about `++b` the same? Would compiler generate `b=true;` instead in this case?

Comment: @Slava: `++b` is now illegal when `b` is type `bool`.  "The type of the
operand shall be an arithmetic type other than *cv* `bool`... If `x` is
not of type bool, the expression `++x` is equivalent to `x+=1`"

Comment: @BenVoigt now means c++11? g++ v5.1.0 though compiles it even with c++11, c++14 and c++17 mode

Comment: Previous wording was "The operand of preﬁx `++` is modiﬁed by adding 1, or set to `true` if it is `bool`  (this use is deprecated)....  The operand of preﬁx `--` is modiﬁed by subtracting 1. The operand shall not be of type `bool`."  The change from deprecated to forbidden prefix `bool` increment was made between draft n4527 (May 2015) and n4582 (March 2016)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes these operations exist, they are found in the C++ standard section 13.6 (note, `bool` is an integral type which makes it an arithmetic type as well):

> For every triple (`L`, `VQ`, `R`), where `L` is an arithmetic type, `VQ` is either `volatile` or empty, and `R` is a promoted arithmetic type, there exist candidate operator functions of the form
>
> ```
> VQ L & operator=(VQ L &, R );
> VQ L & operator*=(VQ L &, R );
> VQ L & operator/=(VQ L &, R );
> VQ L & operator+=(VQ L &, R );
> VQ L & operator-=(VQ L &, R );
> ```

The semantics are defined in section 5.18:

> The behavior of an expression of the form `E1` *`op`* `=` `E2` is equivalent to `E1 = E1` *`op`* `E2` except that E1 is evaluated only once. In `+=` and -=, `E1` shall either have arithmetic type or be a pointer to a possibly cv-qualified completely-defined object type. In all other cases, `E1` shall have arithmetic type.

and

> If the left operand is not of class type, the expression is implicitly converted (Clause 4) to the cv-unqualified type of the left operand.

Answer (score 2):

> it is valid to do the operations with operands that differ?

```
value += exists;
value *= exists;
```

Yes it's valid, the `bool` type is implicitly converted to `int`. It's similar to what you do with operators ( + , - ) with mixed `int` and `short` operands.

Comment: It's treated as one byte by the underlying assembly. Here you can see an example of the C++ input where I'm using bools as if they were integers, but you can also see the `movzx eax, BYTE...` and so on. http://ideone.com/iANO1w